# Why is :nth-child() not working in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$("#oddcolor")[0].onclick = function() { 
  $(".coltest:nth-child(odd)")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<button id="oddcolor">Click me</button>
```

It seems that it applies to only the first odd number element, and then it stops. Why is it not applying to all the odd elements?

I've tried using `querySelectorAll`, and it's not working either. I've tried creating a parent container, and then targeting the child elements via the parent, like this `.parent div:nth-child(odd)`, but again, only applies to the first odd number. I've tried without `jquery`, same result, although, without jquery, if I have to use `getElementsByClassName`, I don't know how to add the `nth-child(odd)`, because `document.getElementsByClassName("coltest:nth-child(odd)")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";` this creates an error, and without the `[0]`, it also creates an error.

It works if I use CSS instead, but why is it not working in Javascript?

Comment: `[0]` extracts the first element of the jQuery collection.

Comment: _"It works if I use CSS instead, but why is it not working in Javascript?"_ -- because they are different things? JavaScript in fact has not much to do with the behaviour you describe. The language itself doesn't know and doesn't care about CSS selectors, HTML, browsers or anything else. The `$` function is provided by a library (jQuery?!) that implements whatever part of CSS selectors its author(s) wanted or could implement.

Comment: The `$(".coltest:nth-child(odd)")[0].style.backgroundColor = "red";` code only makes sense in javascript. $(css-selector) is a jquery function which "return a collection of matched elements either found in the DOM based on passed argument(s) or created by passing an HTML string." from this collection you extract the first element using [0].

Comment: @Salixalba `$()` returns a nodeList, right?

Comment: @Salixalba Actually, what is the difference between just targeting an element with `$()` this, and using `jqueryselector`? How are they different? I know it's not related, but I'm curious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `[0]` only operates on the first element of the jQuery collection. If you want to process all of them, you need a loop.

But since you're using jQuery, use its `.css()` method, which will automatically process every element in the collection.

```js
$("#oddcolor").click(function() { 
  $(".coltest:nth-child(odd)").css('backgroundColor', 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<div class="coltest">test</div>
<button id="oddcolor">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks. I had never heard of `css()` method before.